# Get properties of selected option in Select field

Tags: reactjs

```
countries()
{
    return [{"name":"Afghanistan","code":"AF"},{"name":"Albania","code":"AL"},...];
}

handleCountryChange(e)
{
    console.log('NAME -> ' + e.target.value, ', CODE -> ' + e.target.id);
    // Outputs: NAME -> Afghanistan, CODE -> country     
}

render()
{
    return (
        <select className="form-control country-name" id="country"
        onChange={e => this.handleCountryChange(e)} >

            {countries().map((country, i) => { return ( 
                <option id={country.code} value={country.name} key={i} >
                    {country.name}
                </option> 
            )})}
        </select>
    );
}
```

With an onChange handler on a select element, I'm trying to retrieve the properties of the options. The `country code` and `country name` are stored in its id and value properties respectively. I'm getting the following result

> Outputs: NAME -> Afghanistan, CODE -> country

This means I'm getting the id of the select element and value from the selected option. How do I retrieve the properties of the active `<option>` element from the event that occurred on it, and not the select element itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write it like this to get the attributes of selected item:

```
handleCountryChange(e){
    let index = e.target.selectedIndex;
    let el = e.target.childNodes[index]
    let option =  el.getAttribute('id');  
    console.log('Name, Code', e.target.value, option); 
}
```

Check this example:

```js
let data = [{a:1, b:'a'}, {a:2, b:'b'}, {a:3, b:'c'}];

class App extends React.Component{

 handleCountryChange(e){
     let index = e.target.selectedIndex;
     let el = e.target.childNodes[index]
     let option =  el.getAttribute('id');  
     console.log('Name, Code', e.target.value, option); 
 }

 render(){
     return (
         <select 
          id="country"
          onChange={e => this.handleCountryChange(e)} >
              {
                           data.map((country, i) =>  <option id={country.b} value={country.a} key={i} > {country.a} </option> )
              }
         </select>
     );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: You are a life saver

Comment: glad, it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can send the whole object in the value of an option to use all the properties of the selected object.

```js
getValue(e) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(e.target.value));
  }

  render() {

  let cc = [{
    value: '1st',
    id: 1
  },
  {
   value: '2nd',
    id: 2
  }]
  
  <select onChange={e => this.getValue(e)}>
          <option value={JSON.stringify(cc[0])}>One</option>
          <option value={JSON.stringify(cc[1])}>Two</option>
</select>
}
```

Hope this will help in future with similar problems

Comment: That's wonderful. It's definitely practical to send the whole object in the value of the element. Thanks, Kochar.